# Pick a physical location for a single database in Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have the following issue: I am working on a Macbook Retina with 250gb harddisk space, and 10gb left.

Now, I just got a new customer, who runs their SQL Server database locally (`./SQLEXPRESS`). Problem is their database is 110gb.

That means I am forced to work on an external harddrive on some databases, but I do not want this when I work with my other customers who have less than 50mb databases.

So my question is: how to pick a physical location for a single database in Management Studio?

Comment: SQL Server **Express** has a database size limit of **10 GB** - I doubt that client is running his 110 GB database on SQL Server **Express** ....

Comment: @marc_s: You can run a different edition with the instance name `./SQLEXPRESS`.  Probably to upgrade without modifying the client app.  Used to cause hairy issues with service packs.

Comment: @Andomar: true - but that would definitely violate the *Principle of Least Surprise* ! ....

Comment: @marc_s Maybe it's just the log? If the customer doesn't do proper maintenance and has the full recovery model, it might very well be that there's just a few gigs of data. Or is log file also counted in the limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you [restore a database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx), you can specify where to locate the databases' files.  This is done with the `move` option of the `restore` command:

```
RESTORE DATABASE YourDb
   FROM DISK = 'D:\YourDb.bak'
   MOVE 'YourDb_Data' TO 'c:\newdir\YourDb_Data'
   MOVE 'YourDb_Log' TO 'c:\newdir\YourDb_Log'
   WITH RECOVERY;
```

In SSMS, you can do set the target location in the `Files` tab of the restore wizard.  Edit the `Restore as` column to change the destination.